# What is the difference between Method overriding and method hiding?

Tags: java, static, overriding

Well, I have learned that method overriding is done in non-static methods while method hiding is done for a static method. So what is the difference between them if in method overriding the method of child class is overriding the parent class method so that only method which is of child class is executed?

While in method hiding the same thing is happening that the child class method is hiding the parent class method so that only the child class method is executing?

In the code, I provide below the output of both the program is the same so what is the difference between overriding and hiding.

[image: a pic featuring code]

[image: another pic featuring code]

Comment: Try this with and without keyword static and let us know what you see `parent p = new child(); p.f1(); child c = new child(); c.f1();parent p1 = new parent(); p1.f1();`

Answer (score 0):

The difference can be seen by the code @SMA already mentioned:

```java
public static final void main(String... strings) {
    final Child obj = new MainClass.Child();
    obj.f1();
    final Parent p = obj;
    p.f1();
}
```

will lead to:
Child class
Child class

Whereas the static alternative will lead to:
Child class
Parent class

So in the overriding case the parent method can only be called from the overriding method any more. Whereas in the static case the hidden method still exists and will be called when the corresponding context (hence the parent class) is used.
(I know calling static methods through instances of the class is not a good practice, but it helps to illustrate the answer to this question.)